# How to use derivatives to prove that $f(x)=2\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi }{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right)-\sin \left(x\right)=1$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> I'm supposed to use the derivative to prove that 
>   $$f(x)=2\cos ^2\left(\frac{\pi }{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right)-\sin \left(x\right)=1$$

What I have so far is:

$$f'\left(x\right)=D\left(2\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)^2\right)-D\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)=1$$

$$f\:'\left(x\right)=4\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)-\cos\left(x\right)=1$$

$$f\:'\left(x\right)=-2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right)-\cos\left(x\right)=1$$

And by continuing this I can get all the way to zero, which would mean that $0=1$ and from there by taking the derivative of $1$ we'd get $0=0$, which is obviously true. But what I'm confused about is that even if the constant was any number, let's say two, the equation would still come out as true. And obviously, the original function doesn't equal two.

I'm assuming that I'm somehow supposed to get $1$ to the left side as well? Honestly, I've gone through the formulas so many times, and yet I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Why are you setting $f'(x) = 1$?????

Comment: Note that $D(1) = 0$. So the right hand side of your equations for $f'$ are messed up.

Comment: "But what I'm confused about is that even if the constant was any number, let's say two, the equation would still come out as true. "  Where did you get the idea you were suppose to set the dirivative to a constant?

Comment: If $f'(x) = 0$ for a differentiable function on an open connected domain then the function is constant on that domain. The mean value theorem is your friend.

Comment: fleablood, yeah that's what confused me. I mean we could basically set f(x)=2 and get the same result by taking the derivative, but f(x) can never be 2. Sorry, I'm stupid.

Comment: You aren't supposed to set *anything* to *anything*.  Where did you get that idea from?

Comment: The point is that if you want to show that $f$  is constant, it is sufficient (with a few extra conditions) to show that $f'(x) = 0$. So you differentiate $f$ and show that $f'(x) = 0$. This shows that $f$ is constant, and to get the constant, we evaluate at a convenient point, such as $x=0$.

Comment: Oh I get it now, I'm so stupid.

Comment: Please do not delete posts once they got an answer. If your problem is solved consider accepting an answer. Click the checkmark close to the answer post.

Comment: Note that you cannot prove two functions are equal necessarily by taking derivatives due to the loss of Constants when you take derivatives

Comment: Meta discussion: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29354/10513

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed and deleted by users. It is not unclear what they're asking. (It may not be true, but it is certainly clear!)

Comment: It's an interesting technique, but one it's easy to be confused by initially.

Comment: Who casted the delete vote?

Comment: I think the question needs reopening so a more detailed explanation can be posted of the technique itself.

Answer (score 2):

You have that $f'(x)=0$, so $f(x)=c$. Now substitute a "nice" value into $f$ to get the value of $c$.

Comment: So, is it enough proof to say that cause f'(x)=0, function f(x) is constant, and because the constant is 1, f(x)=1 is also true?

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)$ is
$$2cos^2 \left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right)-sin(x) \ \ \ \ (1) $$

The derivative of $f(x)$ is:

$$f'(x) = 2 * 2* cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right) * \left(-sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right)*(-\frac{1}{2})\right) \iff$$

$$f'(x)=2cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right) sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2}\right)-cos(x)=sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)-cos(x)=0 \ \forall x\in \mathbb R$$

where the identity $sin(2x)=2cos(x)sin(x) $ was used. Now, by knowing $f'(x) = 0 \  \forall x \in \mathbb R $ you can say $$f(x) = c \ \forall x\in \mathbb R$$
based on a consequence of the mean value theorem. If you now set $x=0$ to the initial formula for $f(x), (1) $ you get $f(0)=1$ and thefore: $$ f(x)=1 \ \forall x\in \mathbb R$$